# AngularJS not working on Plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I'm trying to go through a simple tutorial on AngularJS and can't seem to get past the first step. {{ 10 x 10}} isn't appearing as 100. Any ideas?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        {{ 10*10}}
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I just pasted your code in a plunker and it works fine. Can you share your plunk?

Comment: my console is throwing up this error. The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://run.plnkr.co/f4S7wzmXuCyrp326/' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header. Maybe it's down to my companies firewall :(

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this it was down to the company firewall policies.

Answer (score 1):

You might have mentioned multiple versions of ng-app (probably in `<html>` tag).Otherwise your code is working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 10*10}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DnJpRNlg3aqXpzzmmBVg?p=preview)

Comment: Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001134/how-to-create-network-graph-or-hierarchical-tree-using-visjs-in-angularjs) in here my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKfNdsw9g9aCG6wZsQNZ?p=preview) is not working. Please help.